# d3v4 line generator returns NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm just getting started with d3 but I've run into a place that I can't seem to get by. With this simple code, the path that gets generated is `NaN` Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P4Z75/619/

```
let data = [{
  date: '1990-09-01',
  age: 26
}, {
  date: '1990-12-22',
  age: 26
}, {
  date: '1990-05-18',
  age: 27
}, {
  date: '1991-08-24',
  age: 25
}];

var width = 500;
var height = 20;

const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
data = data.map(d => ({
  x: parseTime(d.date),
  y: d.age
}));

const x = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.x)))).range(0, width);

const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.y)))).range(height, 0);

const line = d3.line().x(d => (x(d.x))).y(d => (y(d.y))).curve(d3.curveLinear);

console.log(line(data)) //NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified your scale ranges correctly:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.x)))).range(0, width);

const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.y)))).range(height, 0);
```

Scale ranges, as with domains, take an array:

```
const x = d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.x)))).range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data.map(d => (d.y)))).range([height, 0]);
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s88xayqj/)